# Please change my name

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, users

Also related [UUID displayed instead of username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281019/324325)

There's a bug where my name is messed up, that's besides the point. Please change my name to 'Alex' (no quotes) because it looks bad.
[image]

I don't want my name to be stuck like this until August 13th.

Comment: You should stick with it. I think *a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae* is a very nice name.

Comment: Oddly, your gravatar also appears to be broken.

Comment: What does "***a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae***" mean?

Comment: @Valorum: It is a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), a randomly generated identifier. It doesn’t mean anything a priori.

Comment: I'd laught if a moderator rename you " 'Alex' (no quotes) because it looks bad"

Comment: I just noticed you'd already posted a [question on MSE about this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281019/299342). Please include this relevant background information in the future.

Comment: @Null Ok I'll make sure to do that :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Done

Oddly enough, the name field already had 'Alex' in it. I had to change your avatar to the Identicon in order to change your name. You should be able to change your avatar if you want.

Let us know if you have any other problems.

Comment: Thank you. That name was really annoying

Answer (score 8):

**A moderator can change your name under exigent circumstances.**

Given that your name seems to have been changed to a random string by accident, you would seem to have good reason to get a reset. 
A list of moderators for our Stack Exchange can be found [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). You have sufficient reputation to contact them in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), or you can wait for them to respond to this question.

Comment: You have 25k rep, right? I thought users at  25K had mod tools

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae - We have significant privileges, but not as many as "diamond moderators." For example, I can cast close and delete votes, and edit posts and tag wikis freely.

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae - Well, you may not want to accept this in any case. A moderator will probably post an answer after they have decided what to do about your situation.